# If $f$ is a function such that $f(f(x))=x^{2}-1$ determine the function $f(f(f(f(x))))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, real-numbers

I have tried $f(f(f(f(x))))=f\left(f\left(x^{2}-1\right)\right)$ . Since we know that $f(f(x))=x^{2}-1$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f\left(f\left(x^{2}-1\right)\right) &=\left(x^{2}-1\right)^{2}-1 \\
&= x^{4}-2 x^{2}+1-1 \\
&=x^{4}-2 x^{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$But something doesn't feel right, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: What does not feel right here? The fact that you don't need $f$ itself to find the answer? Finding $f$ is itself part of a whole different field, that of iterative function theory (Read up on "functional square roots"). You were probably expected to solve the question the way you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach given is correct. Perhaps it would feel more natural to be  explicit in our substitution, and write $g(x) = f(f(x))$, so we have $g(x) = x^2-1$, and we are interested in $g(g(x))$.

Then it is easy to see that $g(g(x)) = (x^2-1)^2-1 = x^4-2x^2$.